# Why my hosts file is not visible even after checking the hidden files?

Tags: windows, hosts

I am using windows 10 for a while but the problem is i cant find the hosts file in my "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"  folder. But when i try to create a new one in the same folder it says that there is already one file named "hosts" and asks if i want to replace it. And when i click ok to replace it says "unable to replace. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file is write protected. I started notepad with Administrator but still problem didn't solved. Then i tried to do that using Administrator account but when i try to replace the hosts file with my new one it saved and "hosts(2)"... But i cant see the real one and cant edit that.... How  to solve this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you resolved It ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click `Notepad` and choose `Run as administrator`
In Notepad, click File then Open… In the File name field, paste the following path in:

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

After that, you need to choose all files instead of text files like below
[image]